# mongodb socket file is not created

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, bitnami

I have a ec2 bitnami machine with MEAN stack deployed in it. Whenever I try to access the server from browser, I get a 503 service unavailable error. I found the following error in my server log.

> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: failed to connect to [localhost:27017]
>       at null. (/opt/bitnami/citipage/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:549:74)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
>       at null. (/opt/bitnami/citipage/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Socket. (/opt/bitnami/citipage/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:533:10)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at net.js:440:14
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:459:13)

Guessing that there might some problem with my mongodb, I tried to access mongo shell from terminal using the mongo command. But it throws the following error

> MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10 connecting to:
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/test Tue Mar 24
>   07:12:23.494 Error: couldn't connect to server
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017 at
>   src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147 exception: connect failed

I tried to locate the socket file in the path mentioned in the above error. I found that my /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp folder is empty.

Following is the contents mongodb.conf file

> dbpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db
>   loglogpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
>   logappend=true
>   bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
>   port = 27017
>   auth = true
>   setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0
>   unixSocketPrefix=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp
>   fork = true
>   setParameter = enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0

Below is the contents of mongodb log file

> Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1900  port=27017 dbpath=/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db 32-bit
>   host=ip-172-31-21-94
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten]
>   Tue Mar
>   24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: This is a 32 bit MongoDB
>   binary.
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten] **       32 bit builds
>   are limited to less than 2GB of data (or less with --journal).
>   Tue Mar
>   24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten] **       Note that journaling defaults
>   to off for 32 bit and is currently off.
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887
>   [initandlisten] **       See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/32bit
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten]
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887
>   [initandlisten] db version v2.4.10
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887
>   [initandlisten] git version: e3d78955d181e475345ebd60053a4738a4c5268a
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887 [initandlisten] build info: Linux
>   bs-linux32.10gen.cc 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:39:36 EST
>   2008 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887
>   [initandlisten] allocator: system
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.887
>   [initandlisten] options: { auth: "true", bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config:
>   "mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db", fork: "true",
>   logappend: "true", logpath: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/log/mongodb.log",
>   port: 27017, repair: true, setParameter: [
>   "enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0", "enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0" ],
>   unixSocketPrefix: "/opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp" }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.916
>   [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.916 [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:20.916 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database admin
>   with pdfile version 4.5, new version: 4.5
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.916
>   [initandlisten]    starting upgrade
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.916
>   [initandlisten]  admin repairDatabase admin
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.919
>   [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.ns, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.919 [FileAllocator] creating
>   directory /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:20.925 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.ns, size:
>   16MB,  took 0.004 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.926 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.0, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.929 [FileAllocator] done allocating
>   datafile /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.0,
>   size: 16MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.930 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.1, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.934 [FileAllocator] done allocating
>   datafile /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/admin.1,
>   size: 32MB,  took 0.003 sec
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.936 [initandlisten]
>   build index admin.system.users { user: 1, userSource: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:20.940 [initandlisten]   fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:20.941 [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total
>   records. 0.004 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.941 [initandlisten] build
>   index admin.system.users { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.942
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.943
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 1 total records. 0.001 secs
>    Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949
>   [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [initandlisten] need to
>   upgrade database nextpage-dev with pdfile version 4.5, new version:
>   4.5
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [initandlisten]      starting upgrade
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [initandlisten]  nextpage-dev repairDatabase
>   nextpage-dev
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [FileAllocator] allocating new
>   datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.ns,
>   filling with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.949 [FileAllocator]
>   creating directory
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:20.969 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.ns,
>   size: 16MB,  took 0.005 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.969 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.0,
>   filling with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.973 [FileAllocator] done
>   allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.0,
>   size: 16MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.974 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.1,
>   filling with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.977 [FileAllocator] done
>   allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage-dev.1,
>   size: 32MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.982 [initandlisten]
>   build index nextpage-dev.system.users { user: 1, userSource: 1 }
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:20.984 [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:20.984 [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total
>   records. 0.001 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.984 [initandlisten] build
>   index nextpage-dev.system.users { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.986
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.986
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 1 total records. 0.001 secs
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.988 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.things { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.988 [initandlisten]
>      fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.988 [initandlisten]
>   build index done.  scanned 6 total records. 0 secs
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:20.993 [initandlisten] build index nextpage-dev.users { _id: 1 }
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.995 [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:20.995 [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 85
>   total records. 0.002 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.026 [initandlisten]
>   build index nextpage-dev.sessions { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.027
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.027
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 103 total records. 0 secs
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.040 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.restaurants { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.040
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.040
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 47 total records. 0 secs
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.046 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.offers { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.047 [initandlisten]
>      fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.047 [initandlisten]
>   build index done.  scanned 6 total records. 0 secs
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.072 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.temp_externalcrawls { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.072
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.073
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 44 total records. 0 secs
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.073 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.sessions { expires: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.075
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.075
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 103 total records. 0.002
>   secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.075 [initandlisten] build index
>   nextpage-dev.restaurants { business_id: 1 } background
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.076 [initandlisten]   fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.076 [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 47 total
>   records. 0 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.087 [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar
>   24 06:13:21.087 [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.087
>   [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version
>   4.5, new version: 4.5
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.087 [initandlisten]      starting upgrade
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.087 [initandlisten]  local
>   repairDatabase local
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.088 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.ns, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.088 [FileAllocator] creating
>   directory /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:21.101 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.ns, size:
>   16MB,  took 0.005 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.101 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.109 [FileAllocator] done allocating
>   datafile /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/local.0,
>   size: 16MB,  took 0.007 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128 [initandlisten]
>
> ---
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128 [initandlisten] ****
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database nextpage with
>   pdfile version 4.5, new version: 4.5
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128
>   [initandlisten]    starting upgrade
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128
>   [initandlisten]  nextpage repairDatabase nextpage
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.128 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.ns,
>   filling with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.128 [FileAllocator]
>   creating directory
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/_tmp
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.137 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.ns, size:
>   16MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.137 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.0, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.141 [FileAllocator] done allocating
>   datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.0, size:
>   16MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.142 [FileAllocator]
>   allocating new datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.1, filling
>   with zeroes...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.146 [FileAllocator] done allocating
>   datafile
>   /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data/db/_tmp_repairDatabase_0/nextpage.1, size:
>   32MB,  took 0.003 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.150 [initandlisten] build
>   index nextpage.system.users { user: 1, userSource: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.152 [initandlisten]   fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.152 [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total
>   records. 0.001 secs
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.152 [initandlisten] build
>   index nextpage.system.users { _id: 1 }
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.154
>   [initandlisten]    fastBuildIndex dupsToDrop:0
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.154
>   [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 1 total records. 0.001 secs
>
> Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
>   Tue Mar
>   24 06:13:21.159 dbexit:
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten]
>   shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159
>   [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
>   Tue Mar 24
>   06:13:21.159 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
>   Tue
>   Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs
>   preallocator...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten] shutdown:
>   closing all files...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten]
>   closeAllFiles() finished
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 [initandlisten]
>   shutdown: removing fs lock...
>   Tue Mar 24 06:13:21.159 dbexit: really
>   exiting now

My website is down and I am stuck with this.
Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

When I try to start the mongo using the following command
`sudo mongod --dbpath /opt/bitnami/mongodb/data`
the log is as follows:

> Tue Mar 24 15:32:55.138 [conn1]  authenticate db: nextpage-dev {
>   authenticate: 1, user: "root", nonce: "9ba8c19a0bc84140", key:
>   "81387058670892e86e7b8c98e78cb399" }
>   Tue Mar 24 15:32:55.138 [conn1]
>   auth: couldn't find user root@nextpage-dev, nextpage-dev.system.users

Following is the mongo URI I use in my application
`mongodb://root:password@localhost/nextpage-dev`

Comment: From the log file, the database isn't running - it exited. What happens if you start it again? What command did you use to start it?

Comment: I used sudo mongod -dbpath /opt/bitnami/mongodb/db and this is the output I get    `Tue Mar 24 15:32:55.138 [conn1]  authenticate db: nextpage-dev { authenticate: 1, user: "root", nonce: "9ba8c19a0bc84140", key: "81387058670892e86e7b8c98e78cb399" }
Tue Mar 24 15:32:55.138 [conn1] auth: couldn't find user root@nextpage-dev, nextpage-dev.system.users`